# Crosswalk doesn't update HTML in Ionic

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk

I'm using crosswalk in my ionic app and works fine, but I have a problem:

I'm using an autocomplete maded for me, this autocomplete works perfectly without crosswalk and with crosswalk too if I close and opea again the app.

If I don't close the app, the autocomplete works but crosswalk doesn't load the HTML, from inspect element I see the autocomplete HTML but for any reason is not displaying and there aren't any property that hide the element.

I had test it to disable cache view, reload controller, reload state, but the only thing that works is close and open again the app. After close and open, the autocomplete works forever without problems

I'm working on my final proyect degree and it's important for me.

Any idea?